# Unit Test C# melhor prática

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu tenho um código de teste para um método até que bastante simples de verificação.

```
public bool EmPeriodoDeExigencia(ParametroProrrogacao parametroProrrogacao, Requerimento requerimento)
    {
        PreCondicao
            .Para("Determinar o periodo de exigência do requerimento com ou sem prorrogação")
            .EhSatisfeitaCom("Requerimento deve ser diferente de nulo", requerimento != null);


        if (parametroProrrogacao != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(parametroProrrogacao.Valor))
            return DateTime.Now <= requerimento.DataLimiteParaCumprimentoExigencia.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(parametroProrrogacao.Valor));
        else
            return DateTime.Now <= requerimento.DataLimiteParaCumprimentoExigencia.Value;

    }
```

Neste código as minhas primeiras preocupações é garantir o básico funcionamento do caminho feliz e depois  fazer o teste da lógica e possíveis furos na mesma.

Na maioria das vezes eu entendo que para a lógica é muito simples eu utilizar o padrão AAA, Arrange, Act, Assert, e consigo visualizar isto muito bem.

Porém estou empacado em como utilizar este padrão nesses casos mais triviais de teste, seria este AAA o melhor modo de lidar com esse tipo de teste mais básico também?

Um exemplo de um dos códigos que simplesmente válida se certo parâmetro tiver indo null:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ExcecaoDeCondicao))]
    public void EmPeriodoDeExigencia_ParametroERequerimentoNull()
    {
        servico.EmPeriodoDeExigencia(null, null);
    }
```

Nesse caso eu não consigo enxergar como eu usaria um padrão AAA, sendo que simplesmente meu teste é passar null e atuar no serviço.

E o segundo caso seria este:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EmPeriodoDeExigencia_ParametrosNotNull_ValorNull()
    {
        //Arrange
        var parametro = new Parametro()
        {
            Chave = "DiasProrrogacaoExigenciaAnaliseDocumental",
            Valor = null
        };
        var requerimentoExigencia = new Requerimento(TipoSolicitacao.Registro, 1);
        requerimentoRepaExigencia.RegistrarExigenciaAnaliseDocumental(requerimentoExigencia, 10);

        //act
        servico.EmPeriodoDeExigencia(parametro, requerimentoExigencia);
    }
```

Por que eu passaria, ou como passaria um Assert nesta situação?
Essa é uma pergunta muito mais que conceitual do que para resolver um atual problema, já que os testes estão cobrindo e fazendo seu papel no código, mas se existe eu gostaria de saber uma forma melhor de fazer isso já que sou iniciante nessa parte de testes unitários.

Comment: Usa C# 8? Se não usa, algum motivo? Se usa, não seria melhor que o parâmetro já não aceitasse nulo na compilação?

Comment: Não uso, o motivo é o projeto que estou inserido atualmente no trabalho ser legado, então esse c# ai se não me engano para esse projeto é o c# 6.
DotNet Framework 4.6 no caso, então muitas coisas são outdated mesmo.